Adding a 2nd existing domain to active directory?
TLDR, we just purchased another company and we are trying to add their existing (we'll say @apple.com) domain to our active directory (@paper.com), and have users created their and we can then transfer mailboxes.
We have all users created already under an @paper.com active directory account on our end, and we need to add @apple.com to our active directory (synced with o365) in order to swap those @paper.com addresses over to @apple.com for the time being. We have ownership of their domain.
But how do we get this added as an option to switch to in active directory? Do we add the domain in our DNS server AD Administrative Center?

 as an option to switch to you mean how to connect to the domain. In AD Users and Computers, which is easier, you can right-click in the left pane upper node and select connect to either a domain or domain controller.

Please Contract someone with the Knowledge howto solve your Problem. Serverfault should be only the last resort after a long way of your journey to ask.

It sounds to me like you're asking how to change their UPN suffix from paper.com to apple.com. If that's the case then you need to add the apple.com UPN suffix in the Active Directory Domains and Trusts MMC console, then set the UPN suffix to apple.com for the relevant user accounts.
